# Do subselects do an implicit join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql **query that seems to work but I dont really understand why**. Therefore I would very much appreciate if someone could help explain whats going on:

THE QUERY RETURNS: All organisations that dont have any comments that were not created by the consultant who created the organisation record.

```
SELECT \"organisations\".* 
FROM \"organisations\"  
WHERE \"organisations\".\"id\" NOT IN 
  (SELECT \"comments\".\"commentable_id\" 
     FROM \"comments\"  
     WHERE \"comments\".\"commentable_type\" = 'Organisation' 
     AND (comments.author_id != organisations.consultant_id) 
     ORDER BY \"comments\".\"created_at\" ASC
  )
```

It seems to do so correctly.

**The part I dont understand is why  `(comments.author_id != organisations.consultant_id)` is working!?** I dont understand how postgres even knows what "organisations" is inside that subselect? It is not defined in here.

If this was written as a join where I had joined comments to organisations then I would totally understand how you could do something like this but in this case its a subselect. How does it know how to map the comments and organisations table and exclude the ones where `(comments.author_id != organisations.consultant_id)`

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it know? It's a table.

Comment: @DaveNewton: That comment is neither helpful nor accurate. The subquery knows what *organizations* is  because the scope of the outer query includes the subquery. This type of correlated subquery is not available in all places where a normal subquery is allowed, and varies by vendor and version.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens It's pretty accurate; PostgreSQL knows what `organizations` is because it can't be anything *else* inside that query. You could use other tables other than `organizations`, too (although it wouldn't make much sense). That it's not available across RDBMSs doesn't really affect my comment.

Comment: Please always show **`explain analyze`** output for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

That subselect happens in a row so it can see all columns of that row. You will probably get better performance with this

```
select organisations.* 
from organisations
where not exists (
    select 1
    from comments
    where
        commentable_type = 'organisation'  and
        author_id != organisations.consultant_id
)
```

Notice that it is not necessary to qualify `commentable_type` since the one in `comments` has priority over any other outside the subselect. And if `comments` does not have a `consultant_id` column then it would be possible to take its qualifier out, although not recommended for better legibility.

The `order by` in your query buys you nothing, just added cost.

Answer (score 0):

You are running a correlated subquery. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.105).aspx

This is commonly used in all databases. A subquery in the WHERE clause can refer to tables used in the parent query, and they often do.

That being said, your current query could likely be written better.

Here is one way, using an outer join with comments, where no matches are found based on your criteria -

```
select o.*
  from organizations o
  left join comments c
    on c.commentable_type <> 'Organisation'
   and c.author_id = o.consultant_id
 where c.commentable_id is null
```

Comment: It'll often get optimized to that anyway, if you look at the `explain analyze`.